# "operation not allowed" error during map fragment initialization

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

1. Creating Xamarin Android application
2. Binding HERE-sdk.aar as a binding library into xamarin android application
3. After map.init(this,this) receving "operation not found" in OnEngineInitializationCompleted method
4. The error is like below:

[image]

5. Sample code: https://files.fm/u/tz4wsswa

Comment: can you give us some sample code on how to reproduce and if not then atleast your code so we can guess what is up

Comment: sample code link is shared on: https://files.fm/u/tz4wsswa

Comment: Have you checked your App ID, App Code, and network state? And what android version are you using?